# Error with UIAlertView in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am attempting to display a simple alert view as the first step to create a change calculator app, but every time I try to simulate the app so far, it crashed and won't run. The code I have is...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func showMessage(sender: UIButton) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Welcome to the Change Calculator", message: "Do you wish to continue?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The error that I get is as follows...

```
2016-03-09 23:47:16.385 ChangeMaker[5011:156406] Failed to set (keyPath) user defined inspected property on (UIView): [<UIView 0x7f8210d6fe30> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key keyPath.
2016-03-09 23:47:16.386 ChangeMaker[5011:156406] Failed to set (keyPath) user defined inspected property on (UIView): [<UIView 0x7f8210d6fe30> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key keyPath.
```

or it sometimes sends me into the `AppDelegate.swift` section and says there is some sort of issue with that. Just curious if anyone might know a solution to the issue.

Comment: learn swift http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/display-an-alert-view-in-ios8-with-swift

Answer (score 1):

**This is not your alter view problem please check xib or storyboard and check connection inspector and remove issue it's look like txtPropertyType**

[image]

**This type of error (this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key keyPath) is comes when you create IBOutlet and delete from code**

Comment: The only thing that is under my outlet section is searchDisplayCOntroller

Comment: I was copy your AlertController code in my exiting code it's working well @Jordon and this type (class is not key value coding-compliant) of error comes above case